# $2^{2x}-3 \cdot 2^{x+1}=16 \implies 2^x=-2$ or $2^x=8$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How did they get from $$2^{2x}-3 \cdot 2^{x+1}=16$$ to  $2^x=-2$ or $2^x=8$?

I know that you could also write it as $2^{2x}-3 \cdot 2^{x+1}$

and $2^{2x}-6\cdot 2^x=16$

But I got stuck there...

Comment: It would be helpful if you can think of this as quadratic equation in $2^x$ ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hint* : $$2^x=t\iff t^2-6t-16=0$$

Comment: (t-8)(t+2)=0 t=8 or t=-2 so $2^x=8$ or $2^x=-2$